# How do I deal with vim buffers when switching git branches?

Tags: git, vim, buffer, version, branch

So, I've got a ton of files open in my vim buffer, and I'm working on a feature branch with git. Suddenly, I realize that I need to revert back to my master branch to make a quick fix.

After making my commits, I leave my vim session open and switch back over to the master branch. However, when I try and load the files I need from the buffer, I now get the message

```
Warning: File "<filename>" has changed since editing started
```

This makes complete since to me. The file in the buffer is from my feature branch, and now that I have switched back to master branch, there are understandably some deltas to deal with.

My question is, how is this situation dealt with on a professional level?

Thinking of solutions, I could just close all the buffers and re-open the files. However, I was hoping there is a "smart" way to do this. Is there a way to replace the files in the current vim buffer with their counterparts in the desired branch? Is there a way of maintaining multiple buffers, one per git branch?

Ultimately, I want to be able to switch between git branches, and have the open vim session just "know" which version of the file should currently reside in the buffer.

Part of this is that I am still learning about how vim buffers work, and have just started to use them extensively. So if I made any assumptions that don't hold, please correct me where appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a `:bufdo e` to force vim to reread all the open buffer from the  filesystem.

`bufdo` is a way to apply a command to multiple buffers. (Similarly there is a `tabdo` if you are using tabs)

So it will replace the version of the old branch by the version of the new branch.

(Similar question & answer there : [Git branching while files are opened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624498/513198) )

Comment: You answered my question perfectly. Follow up question. Why does doing this change the text of my vim session to one color? If this doesn't immediately jog your memory of a common problem, don't worry about it. It is a minor issue.

Comment: The `:bufdo` turns off event processing, so syntax highlighting isn't activated.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend you `:set autoread` in your `~/.vimrc`:

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
>     it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.

Comment: This is probably easier, but is sometimes cumbersome when you are editing live log files.

Comment: @XavierT. As this option is global-local, you can always turn it off for a buffer with `:setlocal noar`.